# Find pairs of list elements that have remainder <= some number

Tags: python

Let's say my target number is 60. I have a list of elements and I would like to find pairs of numbers that when subtracted have a remainder that is less than or equal to 60 (abs value is okay). When I find the numbers, I want to add them to a new list, without having any duplicates.

Here's my code, but this is providing tons of duplicates.

Contents of `new_days` are: `[353, 34, 172, 218, 356, 37, 83, 175, 267, 177, 269, 361, 88, 134, 180, 226, 272, 318, 364, 45]`

```
i, j = 0, 1

pairs = []

for i in range(len(new_days)):
    for j in range(len(new_days)):
        val = new_days[j] - new_days[i]
        val = abs(val)
        if val <= 60:
            pair = str(new_days[i]) + ' ' + str(new_days[j])
            pairs.append(pair)
```

I would like to keep the code as simple and clean as possible so that my boss and coworker who both know a little bit of Python can understand once i'm done with it, should any changes need to be made.

Comment: `itertools.combinations`

Answer (score 2):

In order to **filter all pairs following the given criterion**, you may use [**`itertools.combinations`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) along with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> my_list = [353, 34, 172, 218, 356, 37, 83, 175, 267, 177, 269, 361, 88, 134, 180, 226, 272, 318, 364, 45]

#                                        filter criterion  v
>>> [(i,j) for i, j in combinations(my_list, 2) if abs(i-j)<=60]
[(353, 356), (353, 361), (353, 318), (353, 364), (34, 37), (34, 83), (34, 88), (34, 45), (172, 218), (172, 175), (172, 177), (172, 134), (172, 180), (172, 226), (218, 175), (218, 267), (218, 177), (218, 269), (218, 180), (218, 226), (218, 272), (356, 361), (356, 318), (356, 364), (37, 83), (37, 88), (37, 45), (83, 88), (83, 134), (83, 45), (175, 177), (175, 134), (175, 180), (175, 226), (267, 269), (267, 226), (267, 272), (267, 318), (177, 134), (177, 180), (177, 226), (269, 226), (269, 272), (269, 318), (361, 318), (361, 364), (88, 134), (88, 45), (134, 180), (180, 226), (226, 272), (272, 318), (318, 364)]
```

However, in case you want to **filter the pairs of only consecutive numbers**, you may use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with *list comprehension* expression:

```
#    filter content on absolute value of consecutive number  v
>>> [(i, j) for i, j in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]) if abs(i-j)<=60]
[(172, 218), (37, 83), (88, 134), (134, 180), (180, 226), (226, 272), (272, 318), (318, 364)]
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear in asking my question, but this wouldn't include something such as `(37, 45)` would it?

Comment: `(37, 83)` is present in the example I mentioned, *so will be `(37, 45)` if present* :). If the absolute value of the difference of two consecutive value is less than 60, it will be present as pair in the resultant list.

Comment: The numbers don't have to be consecutive. It would be if ANY two numbers have a difference of abs(60)

Comment: @Harrison check edit. 1st will include all the pairs, 2nd will include consecutive pair

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will go through all pairs (without repeating them in other order):

```
for i, e1 in enumerate(data):
    for e2 in data[i+1:]:
        if abs(e1 - e2) <= 60:
            print(e1, e2)
```